# how to manually login using cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

```
    public function login()
    {
        if (!empty($this->request->is("post"))) {

           $emailid = $this->request->data("emailid");
           $password = $this->request->data("password");
           $options = array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Register.emailid',
                'Register.password',
                ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'emailid = $emailid',
                'password = $password',
                ),
            );
           $userdata = $this->Register->find()->first('$options');

 if ($emailid == $userdata['emailid'] && $password == $userdata['password'])
        {
            $session = $this->request->session();
            $session->write('emailid', $emailid);
            $session->write('userid', $userdata['id']);
            debug($session);
            $this->Flash->success(__('thank you for log in'));
            //return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'register','action' => 'adminpannel']);
        }else{

          $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));

      }
  }
}
```

this is my code for manually login using sessions.but I am not getting output.
i printed $emailid and $password and userdata['emailid'] and user['password'] but they are not same

Comment: Why aren't you using CakePHP's built in authentication? There's quite a few security issues you would avoid by following this: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: i tried but my auth componet is not properly working.

Comment: Auth->identify() is not properly working . it showing false. I tried every possibly way  but I failed so I decided to do manually

Comment: I think you would be way better off trying to figure out why the auth component didn't work for you then! :)